# push notification using phonegap + jQuery mobile

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am beginner, I am making a simple app of push notification. Can I check that functionality on simulator (iPhone simulator).

And second can you please give some steps how to start. I Googled it find there is plugin. I know how to add plugin but There is some thing I need to register or making account?

Please give some step How to make simple application of push notification on simulator?

Answer (score 0):

For testing push notifications, you need proper hardware(simulator will not work), Apple 99$ developer account and push enabled provisioning profile.